# Can Anyone help me with this GoLand terminal Error

Tags: go

I'm using GoLand IDE and I'm getting a problem when running my Go web app. The code isn't compiling when the Terminal is used.

Here is the problem: The terminal duplicated the command prompt when I make an attempt at running the code.

```
C:\Users\Evan\go\src\awesomeProject9>go run main.go

C:\Users\Evan\go\src\awesomeProject9>
```

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "html/template"
  "net/http"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func init(){
  template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("templates/index", idx)
  http.ListenAndServe("8000", nil)
  fmt.Println("hello World")
}

func idx(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "templates/index.html", nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean that it duplicated the command prompt?

Comment: Instead of running the code, the command prompt restarts automatically.

Comment: Can you post the contents of main.go?

Comment: package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "html/template"
 "net/http"
)
var tpl *template.Template

func init(){
 template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
}

func main() {
 http.HandleFunc("templates/index", idx)
 http.ListenAndServe("8000", nil)
 fmt.Println("hello World")

}

func idx(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
 tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "templates/index.html", nil)
}

Comment: I moved that to the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/zFDc5BxLduh

Comment: I created an Edit, Everything is all above!

Comment: I'm noticing that its panicing. It seems likely you are not seeing stderr. To test this, can you place `fmt.Println("hello world")` before your `template.Must()`?

Comment: Perfect! now how do I execute the Html pages?

Comment: Well what I was suggesting was the panic stack trace would probably show you what is wrong. I'm wondering if you place a stdout println (fmt.Println()) would you see it. If so, then you can figure out why you aren't seeing the stacktrace.

Comment: Alright! thanks a ton! I made a lot of progress thanks to your help!

Comment: Good deal. Good luck

Comment: Your listen address is invalid. Don't ignore the error returned by `http.ListenAndServe`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @zerkms for pointing out, that I was wrong. I simply ran into the exact mistake I tried to warn you later on:

you really should use the err returned by called functions, since these really help you a lot! For startes simply:

```
err := http.ListenAndServe("8000", nil)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

This panics with:

```
2018/12/18 10:43:16 listen tcp: address 8000: missing port in address
```

the correct line should be

```
err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
```

**WRONG** only for documentation

`ListenAndServe` doesn't block the further code execution....

Comment: "`ListenAndServe` doesn't block the further code execution" --- it certainly does, if successful.